# Wordpress is_page() for blog post listing page

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use an is_page() conditional in Wordpress to detect whether or not the current page is the blog listing page (or a blog post page actually). The conditional works fine for any other page (contact, whats-on etc) but for some reason it doesn't work for the blog page.

Plus the actual blog post pages - URLs are www.domain.com/the-post-title format, so I can't check for 'blog' in the URL from $_SERVER or anything. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We need to check:

- if this page is blog page.
- if this page is "page for posts"

  ```
  function is_page_for_posts() {
      $result = false;

      if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) {
          $page = get_queried_object();

          $result = ! is_null( $page ) && $page->ID == get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
      }

      return $result;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do a combination of is_home() - if your home page is the blog

or is_single() based on the type of blog post

reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Single_Post_Page

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately the blog page isn't home, it's on /blog. I don't understand why if(is_page('contact')) is true for the Contact Us page, but if(is_page('blog')) is not true for Blog. I've also tried the page id (5) with the same result.

Comment: ensure that what you are trying to retrieve is the actual "slug" of the 'blog' page

Comment: Ah you're a genius! Thank you! Worked perfectly for /blog so just need a solution for actual blog post pages?

Comment: post pages can be defined and checked by is_single()

Comment: is_single() is the post, is_home() is the blog listing. Check out the related tags on the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-homepage-conditional/) article, this is how you use these kind of conditional functions:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ){
    // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page()){
    //Static homepage
} elseif ( is_home()){
    //Blog page
} else {
    //everything else
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep this in mind for future. is_home() for blog post listing page... not intuitive at all. Intuitive would be matching those functions to those comments - is_default_homepage(), is_blog_page() etc. Ah well, I'll remember this for future :-)